# Passing a bound object method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

For a Firefox extension, I'm trying to do the following:

1. Setup an object with two methods and a field/property/attribute
2. One of the methods has to be able to call the other method and access the attribute
3. I want to register that method as an event listener.

Right now, I have it setup like a class:

```
var Obj = {
  field: null,
  a: function() { }
  b: function() {
    Obj.field = 'x';
    Obj.a();
  }
}

window.addEventListener('mouseup', Obj.b, false);
```

But it seems like it should be possible to have the mod not refer to the object "from the outside" (e.g. by using `Obj`), but using just `this` instead. However, I can't figure out how to get this to work correctly, pass a simple function reference to `addEventListener()` *and* (preferably) only polluting the namespace with a single name. Is that possible? I tried googling for it and found e.g. http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/, but that didn't seem to lead to something that fits my criteria of a clean setup.

Comment: The value of `this` in JavaScript is very dynamic. It is a *calling context*, meaning it is generally set when the function is called, and differs based on *how* it was called. You should probably read a tutorial on the various ways that `this` is set. Some are implicit, some are explicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ES5 [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function:

```
var Obj = {
  field: null,
  a: function() { }
  b: function() {
    this.a = 'x';
    this.a();   //Note: not sure what you're trying to do, but calling a string like a function won't work.
  }
}

window.addEventListener('mouseup', Obj.b.bind(Obj), false);
```

Answer (score 3):

`bind` is definitely a good approach. However, notice that `addEventListener` method can accept object that implements the [EventListener](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventListener) interface, instead of a function:

```
var Obj = {
  field: null,
  a: function() { },
  b: function() {
    this.field = 'x'; // if you overrides `a` you can't call it
    this.a();
  },

  handleEvent: function(event) {
    switch(event.type) {
      case "mouseup":
         this.b();
         break;
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener('mouseup', Obj, false);
```

This can be useful if you have multiple events related to `Obj`, and/or if you have multiple instances of the same object (not your case).