# JS: Calling a function inside the object within the same object

Tags: javascript, function

So, I have this:

```
var listener = {
    _handleMessage: function(b) {
        var c = b.data;
        if (c) this.{c}; //this not works
    },
    testFunc: function() {
        console.log("success");
    }
    startListen: function() {
        window.addEventListener("message", this._handleMessage, !1)
    }
};

listener.startListen();
```

What to be expected: when a data passes through `startListen`, it will pass data to `_handleMessage`. From there, it checks the data to call a function INSIDE the listener as well (for example, the `testFunc` will be called if `b.data` is `testFunc`).

Using something like I post does not work. Using `this[c]();` does not work either `(this[c] is not a function)`. Any other solutions?

**SOLVED**

Found a more elegant way:

```
_handleMessage: function(b) {
        var c = b.data;
        if (c) {
            var d = listener[c.action];
            d && "function" == typeof d (function() {
                d.call(listener, c.params || {});
            });
        }
    },
```

Comment: Your "more elegant way" doesn't make a whole lot of sense, but then neither does `this.{c}`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing a bound object method in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260903/passing-a-bound-object-method-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you have:

```
window.addEventListener("message", this._handleMessage, !1);
```

the *_handleMessage* function is passed to the element handler. When called by the handler, its *this* is set to the element whose handler is calling the function, not the *listener* object. You can fix that as indicated by StriplingWarrior, or you can do something like:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(){listener._handleMessage()}, false)
```

so that *this* in *_handleMessage* is set to the object you expect (i.e. *listener*).

#### Edit

In your "solved" code:

```
        d && "function" == typeof d (function() {
            d.call(listener, c.params || {});
        });
```

As long as *d* resolves to a truthy value, then the function in the grouping operator is **always** evaluated, it doesn't matter what `typeof d` returns, so you effectively have:

```
        d && d.call(listener, c.params || {});
```

so:

```
    if (c) {
        var d = listener[c.action];
        d && "function" == typeof d (function() {
            d.call(listener, c.params || {});
        });
    }
```

might as well be:

```
    if (c && listener[c.action]) {
        listener[c.action](c.params || {});
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked and answered a number of times. You need to specify `this._handleMessage.bind(this)` so that `_handleMessage` has a context (a `this`). This is equivalent, although some might say more concise, to using `function(b) { self._handleMessage(b); })` as other answers suggested.

The precise same logic applies to any case where you are passing a class method as a callback, such as to `setTimeout`.

The above is most simple, but there are other approaches. If you need a bound version of `_handleMessage` in multiple places, it might be useful to pre-bind it:

```
listener._handleMessage = listener._handleMessage.bind(listener);
```

Or, you could use Underscore's [`_.bindAll`](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll):

```
_.bindAll(listener, '_handleMessage');
```

Or, you could do it in an `init` function inside the object:

```
var listener = {
    _handleMessage: function(b) {
        var c = b.data;
        if (c) this.{c}; //this not works
    },
    startListen: function() {
        window.addEventListener("message", this._handleMessage, !1)
    },
    init: function() {
        this._handleMessage = this._handleMessage.bind(this);
        return this;
    }
}.init();
```

If you are working in an ES6 environment, fat arrow functions solve this problem by [defining `this` lexically](http://es6rocks.com/2014/10/arrow-functions-and-their-scope/#scope), so you can just do

```
window.addEventListener("message", b => this._handleMessage(b), !1);
```

In this case, the `this` is not the value of the context with which the function is invoked by the event machinery (typically the global object), but rather the surrounding `this`, which is what you want.

As for the `this.{c}`, no idea what you're trying to do there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if I bind every method it will be a lot of code later(the method keeps growing). Any way to shorthand something like this:

 `init: function() {
  this._handleMessage = this._handleMessage.bind(this);
  this._postMessage  = this._postMessage.bind(this);
  this.websiteOpenEmbed  = this.websiteOpenEmbed.bind(this);
  return this;
 }`

Comment: Yes, you could `_.bindAll` inside the `init`: `_.bindAll(this, '_handleMessage', '_postMessage', 'websiteOpenEmbed');`. Or `['_handleMessage', '_postMessage', 'websiteOpenEmbed'].forEach(function(method) { this[method] = this[method].bind(this); }, this);`

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `this` in JavaScript refers to the context that the function was called in at runtime. Your event listener is not getting invoked in the context of your `listener` object when the "message" event fires.

Try creating an anonymous function to serve as the handler, and make sure that it invokes the event in the right context, like so:

```
var listener = {
    _handleMessage: function(b) {
        var c = b.data;
        if (c) this.{c}; //this not works
    },
    testFunc: function() {
        console.log("success");
    }
    startListen: function() {
        var t = this; // capture "this" when `listener.startListen()` is invoked.
        window.addEventListener("message", function(b) {t._handleMessage(b);}, !1)
    }
};

listener.startListen();
```

Comment: Thanks, but the listener is invoked even without capturing it. And I have solved it (edited question). Thanks for your time.

Comment: "*this in JavaScript refers to the context that the function was called in at runtime*". "context" more correctly refers to *execution context*, which is quite a different thing to *this*, which has nothing to do with the *execution context* that the function was called from. ;-)

Comment: @user2002495: I know the listener was getting invoked, but when it was getting invoked "this" was not pointing to the `listener` object, was it? The code I provided was one of several ways to solve this problem.

Comment: @RobG: Thanks for the feedback. Can you please provide better wording to concisely describe what `this` is?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: yes but I did it in another way, see torazaburo's comments above